# Location of label edges in Tikz Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I have made the following graph[image]

It corresponds to the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\path
+(0,-0.75)     node[circle,draw,scale=2, fill=white!50] (S) {}
+(0,0.75)     node[circle,draw,scale=2, fill=white!50] (K) {}
+(-3.5,1.5)  node[circle,draw, scale = 2,fill=white!50]  (x1) {}
+(-3.5,0)    node[circle,draw, scale = 2, fill=white!50]  (x2) {}
+(-3.5,-1.5) node[circle,draw, scale = 2,fill=white!50]  (x3) {};
\draw[->] (x1)--(S) node[pos=.8,above]{$\omega_{1,1}^{(2)}$};
\draw[->] (x2)--(S) node[pos=.8,above]{$\omega_{1,2}^{(2)}$};
\draw[->] (x3)--(S) node[pos=.8,above]{$\omega_{1,3}^{(2)}$};
\draw[->] (x1)--(K) node[pos=.1,above]{$\omega_{1,1}^{(2)}$};
\draw[->] (x2)--(K) node[pos=.1,above]{$\omega_{1,2}^{(2)}$};
\draw[->] (x3)--(K) node[pos=.1,above,bend left=50]{$\omega_{1,3}^{(2)}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Obviously, the weight labels are not looking very neat. I would like the weights to be something like the following picture;

[image]

That also bring me to my next question: How to add the large curly bracket followed by an equation on the right hand side? Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are! parameters `\a`, `\b` make the code easier to adjust!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} % for brace 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[n/.style={circle,fill=gray!50,minimum size=8mm}]
\def\a{2}
\def\b{3.5}
\path
(0,0)        node[n] (R)  {}
+(0,\a)      node[n] (Ru) {}
+(0,-\a)     node[n] (Rb) {}
+(\b,.5*\a)  node[n,outer sep=1mm] (Lu) {}
+(\b,-.5*\a) node[n,outer sep=1mm] (Lb) {};
\draw[->] (Ru)--(Lu) node[pos=.2,above=-1mm,sloped]  {$\omega_{1,1}$};
\draw[->] (Ru)--(Lb) node[pos=.85,above=-1mm,sloped] {$\omega_{2,1}$};
\draw[->] (R)--(Lu)  node[pos=.2,above=-1mm,sloped]  {$\omega_{1,2}$};
\draw[->] (R)--(Lb)  node[pos=.75,above=-1mm,sloped] {$\omega_{2,2}$};
\draw[->] (Rb)--(Lu) node[pos=.2,above=-1mm,sloped]  {$\omega_{1,3}$};
\draw[->] (Rb)--(Lb) node[pos=.7,above=-1mm,sloped]  {$\omega_{2,3}$};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace},gray] (\b+1,\a)--(\b+1,-\a);
\path (\b+1.5,0) node[right]{$\mathbf{\Omega=}$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Does adding 'sloped'  do the trick or was it something else?

Comment: Yeah, `sloped` makes text sloped along the `path`. You can test it youself!

Answer (score 4):

Just a few changes to your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}

\[
\left.
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=to,baseline]
\path
+(0,-1)     node[circle,scale=2, fill=lightgray] (S) {}
+(0,1)     node[circle,scale=2, fill=lightgray] (K) {}
+(-3,1.5)  node[circle, scale = 2,fill=lightgray]  (x1) {}
+(-3,0)    node[circle,scale = 2, fill=lightgray]  (x2) {}
+(-3,-1.5) node[circle, scale = 2,fill=lightgray]  (x3) {};
\draw[->, gray] (x1)--(S) node[sloped, pos=.8,above, yshift=-1mm, black]{\small$\omega_{2,1}$};
\draw[->, gray] (x2)--(S) node[sloped, pos=.8,above, yshift=-1mm, black]{\small$\omega_{2,2}$};
\draw[->, gray] (x3)--(S) node[sloped, pos=.8,above, yshift=-1mm, black]{\small$\omega_{2,3}$};
\draw[->, gray] (x1)--(K) node[sloped, pos=.2,above, yshift=-1mm, black]{\small$\omega_{1,1}$};
\draw[->, gray] (x2)--(K) node[sloped, pos=.2,above, yshift=-1mm, black]{\small$\omega_{1,2}$};
\draw[->, gray] (x3)--(K) node[sloped, pos=.2,above, yshift=-1mm, black]{\small$\omega_{1,3}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad\right\}\quad\Omega=
\]
\end{document}
```

- `fill=lightgray` to color the nodes (or you can use `gray!50` or any percentage
- delete `draw` to remove border circles
- `gray` for arrow color (but `black` for label color)
- include `sloped` to have labels follow arrows
- negative `yshift` to reduce space between arrow and label
- `>=to` for desired arrowheads
- `baseline` so that the brace is placed correctly with respect to the diagram
- `\left.` and `\right\}` for right-only brace
- `\small` to reduce label sizes. (`\footnotesize` would be even smaller)

[image]